# offsetting the mean on a scatter plot?

Tags: r

[the figure wth offset points but mean in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzqCf.jpg)
I'm plotting two sets of data on the same plot, distinguishing the two sets by using different pch and by offsetting them. I also want to plot the mean of both sets of data but so far I've only been able to offset the data points, not the means. This is my code

```
points(jitter(as.numeric(gen$genord)-0.1,0.1),ai$propaiacts, pch=15,col="dimgray",cex=1)
points(jitter(as.numeric(ugen$genord)+0.1,0.1),uai$propuaiacts, pch=6)
s=split(gen$propaiacts,gen$gencode)
points(jitter(sapply(s,  mean)+0.5,0.5),pch="__", cex=2)
s=split(ugen$propuaiacts,ugen$gencode)
points(jitter(sapply(s,  mean)-0.1,0.1),pch="__", cex=2)
```

this is the relevant data:

```
dput(c(gen$genord,gen$propaiacts))
c(3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 13.5986733, 6.6115702, 
9.2198582, 0.6001775, 1.0177719, 6.4348071, 10.0849649, 16.5116934, 
11.00971, 14.2514897, 4.366077, 7.3884464)
> dput(c(ugen$ugenord,ugen$propuaiacts))
c(3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 9.4512195, 6.3064133, 
7.2121554, 0.6486974, 1.0140406, 5.9735066, 10.076442, 12.5423729, 
9.6563923, 13.3744272, 4.4930535, 5.3341665, 21.0191083)
```

Comment: can you include your dataset in your post?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9zu6pwv2m2wqc1/scatterplots%20fraction%20ai.R?dl=0https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2st5ql2ouzkoc8/sadata.csv?dl=0

Comment: not your code, but your dataset. just run in R: dput(gen), dput(ugen) and copy and paste in your pose. It does not have to be your all dataset, just enough to reproduce what you want :)

Comment: thanks, but hang on, dput is new to me, may take a while to work out.

Comment: I got warnings when I run dput(c(gen$genord,gen$propaiacts)); see my answer for now until you learn how to use dput()

Answer (score 0):

using your code and dataset was difficult, so I will use the iris dataset and hopefully it will help you started. As an alternative to your base R, I used `ggplot2`. I only converted the data from wide to long. And then I just added `position = position_dodge(width = 1)` to the `geom_point()` expression. To add the mean for each group (black dot), I summarised the dataset iris_melt. Hope it will help you to get what you want.

```
iris_melt <- melt(iris, id.vars=c("Species"))

iris_melt_s <- ddply(iris_melt, c("Species", "variable"), summarise,
               meanv = mean(value))

iris_melt <- melt(iris, id.vars=c("Species"))

ggplot(data=iris_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value, group=Species, color=Species, shape=Species)) + 
geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
geom_point(data=iris_melt_s, aes(x=variable, y=meanv, group=Species, color=Species), color="black", position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I should definitely get into ggplot2. I just don't have the time to recode the plot at the moment. Do you or anyone know how I can shift the mean markers to be in line the points just using base graphics?

Comment: i realised that I could specify the number of categories on the x and then shift it. It's a bit manual, but it worked for now. 
s=split(ai$propaiacts,ai$recallord)
points(c(1,2,3)-0.1,sapply(s,  mean), pch="__", cex=2)

Answer (score 0):

i realised that I could simply specify the number of categories on the x and then shift it. It's a bit manual, but it worked for now. s=split(ai$propaiacts,ai$recallord) points(c(1,2,3)-0.1,sapply(s, mean), pch="__", cex=2)